# Cannot read property '$$OwnerKey$$' of null

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out, lightninginput

I have a Visualforce Lightning Out page that's rendering some `<lightning:input type="date">` elements. Since the Winter '19 release in the dev sandbox I'm working in, whenever I select a date from the calendar that appears when focusing the element, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$OwnerKey$$' of null throws at https://my--namespace--c.cs53.visual.force.com/auraFW/javascript/DKtn8n91I9aoLMj6o4CurQ/aura_prod.js:2:1559

[image: Cannot read property '$$OwnerKey$$']

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Is it a Winter '19 bug? Is there any corresponding Known Issue?

Comment: Yes,We also got same error on Lightning date field..Reported to salesforce.

Comment: My custom datepicker does not do this - here: https://github.com/rapsacnz/DatePicker

Comment: I just started receiving this on a VF page with a Lightning component in a Winter '19 environment, but it only throws this error on Android phones.  Desktop and iOS (iphone and ipad) running same code does not throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was a [Winter '19 bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000031AmQAI), which has since been fixed in the [Winter '19 Patch 7.0](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=216007000).

The issue previously could be reproduced using the following steps:

1. Create a [lightning:recordForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation) component or a [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) component for entering a date.
2. Edit the record, and select a new date.

These steps would result in the following error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: XXXXXXXXXX)
>
> [Cannot read property '$$OwnerKey$$' of null]