# Error: Cannot read property '$$OwnerKey$$' of null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component and I'm using `lightning:pill` to show selected ids. Whenever I call the `onitemremove` I get this error

> [Cannot read property '$$OwnerKey$$' of null]

I've managed to pinpoint that using the `splice` function causes the error. I'm also using jQuery 224.

HTML

```
<lightning:pillContainer aura:id="pillContainer" items="{!v.selectedProductIds}" onitemremove="{!c.removeItem}"/>
```

Controller.js

```
removeItem : function(component, event, helper){
    helper.removeItem(component, event);
},
```

Helper.js

```
removeItem : function(component, event){
    var index = event.getParam("index");
    var items = component.get('v.selectedProductIds');

    items.splice(index, 1);
    component.set('v.selectedProductIds', items);   

},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cannot read property '$$OwnerKey$$' of null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/232415/2995)

Comment: Pretty sure that either items or index are null. Or index is greater than the array length. Also, check that index is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a known issue in the Winter '19 release that hasn't been resolved yet.  It's related to inputfields though.  I wouldn't have thought of pillcontainer as in input!  Seems like a very specific error message though.  Take a look:

[Lightning input fields throw error: Cannot read property '$$OwnerKey$$' of null](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000031AmQAI)